# Python, Pandas ffill() does not work on object columns

Tags: python, pandas, fill

Here is the sample dataFrame:

```
data = np.matrix([[4,3,6,4,1,7,5,5], [1,2,3,6,4,2,4,9], ['a',np.nan, np.nan, 'b', np.nan, 'c', np.nan, 'd'],[1,np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 2]]).T
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> data

   0  1    2    3
0  4  1    a    1
1  3  2  nan  nan
2  6  3  nan  nan
3  4  6    b    2
4  1  4  nan  nan
5  7  2    c    2
6  5  4  nan  nan
7  5  9    d    2

>>> data.dtypes

0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
dtype: object
```

As you can see, the `dtypes` for some of the columns are `object`. They are not `float`, or `int`.

If I type in, `data.ffill()`, to the Console, it doesn't do anything. But, If I try `data[3] = data[3].astype(float).ffill()`

it changes `data` to:

```
   0  1    2    3
0  4  1    a  1.0
1  3  2  nan  1.0
2  6  3  nan  1.0
3  4  6    b  2.0
4  1  4  nan  2.0
5  7  2    c  2.0
6  5  4  nan  2.0
7  5  9    d  2.0
```

Apparently pd.ffill() works only on numeric columns, but not on string columns. `data[2] = data[2].astype(str).ffill()` didn't change anything. How can I forward fill on rows with `dtype=object`?

Here is the output I want:

```
   0  1    2    3
0  4  1    a  1.0
1  3  2    a  1.0
2  6  3    a  1.0
3  4  6    b  2.0
4  1  4    b  2.0
5  7  2    c  2.0
```

- I extracted data from csv using pd.read_csv(). In the original csv file, some columns of numeric values and some have string columns

Comment: The object `nan` is literally the string `'nan'` which will not be recognized as a null value by pandas. When you first do `astype(float)` all of the values become true `np.NaN` null values and so `ffill` recognizes them appropriately, since the string `'nan'` has no numeric equivalent while the string `'1'` can unambiguously be cast into a number.

Comment: @ALollz Any neat solution to replace string 'nan' with previous values, other than extracting with non-str dtype in the firstplace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of the strings are just being stored as `'nan'` then you can fill the entire `DataFrame` in one line. `None` is a recognized null value that works for the object type.

```
data.mask(data=='nan', None).ffill()

#0    4    1    a    1
#1    3    2    a    1
#2    6    3    a    1
#3    4    6    b    2
#4    1    4    b    2
#5    7    2    c    2
#6    5    4    c    2
#7    5    9    d    2
```

Comment: Didn't work for my case but this one did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74292112/10789707