# Pandas ffill() to fill missing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, ffill

I am currently trying to fill blanks in a data frame that looks like the following:

```
       AL|ATFC|Year Latitude Longitude
0      AL011851      NaN       NaN
1           NaN    28.0N     94.8W
2           NaN    28.0N     95.4W
3           NaN    28.0N     96.0W
4           NaN    28.1N     96.5W
5           NaN    28.2N     96.8W
6           NaN    28.2N     97.0W
7           NaN    28.3N     97.6W
8           NaN    28.4N     98.3W
9           NaN    28.6N     98.9W
10          NaN    29.0N     99.4W
11          NaN    29.5N     99.8W
12          NaN    30.0N    100.0W
13          NaN    30.5N    100.1W
14          NaN    31.0N    100.2W
15     AL021851      NaN       NaN
16          NaN    22.2N     97.6W
17     AL031851      NaN       NaN
18          NaN    12.0N     60.0W
```

I have been trying the following line of code with the goal to fill the `AL|ATFC|Year` column where I have `NaN` values with the pandas ffill() function.

`df.where(df['AL|ATFC|Year'] == float('NaN'), df['AL|ATFC|Year'].ffill(), axis=1, inplace=True)`

To get the following dataframe:

```
    AL|ATFC|Year Latitude Longitude
0      AL011851      NaN       NaN
1      AL011851    28.0N     94.8W
2      AL011851    28.0N     95.4W
3      AL011851    28.0N     96.0W
4      AL011851    28.1N     96.5W
5      AL011851    28.2N     96.8W
6      AL011851    28.2N     97.0W
7      AL011851    28.3N     97.6W
8      AL011851    28.4N     98.3W
9      AL011851    28.6N     98.9W
10     AL011851    29.0N     99.4W
11     AL011851    29.5N     99.8W
12     AL011851    30.0N    100.0W
13     AL011851    30.5N    100.1W
14     AL011851    31.0N    100.2W
15     AL021851      NaN       NaN
16     AL021851    22.2N     97.6W
17     AL031851      NaN       NaN
18     AL031851    12.0N     60.0W
```

Thereafter, I am planning the drop row with missing Lon/Lat values. However, the code I have been trying to use does not work to fill in the missing values in the `AL|ATFC|Year` column and I don't understand why...Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: can you share the DF as a code? NaN is float, and it might be converted to string, since the values are alphanumeric.

Comment: The dataframe is actually much bigger and read in from a csv. I can confirm that the NaN values are float and the existing values in `AL|ATFC|Year` are strings.

Comment: creating the DF from your example, it worked for me. check the very first null value type after the valid value .  type(df['AL|ATFC|Year'].iloc[1])

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `'AL|ATFC|Year'` NaN by `np.nan`, and then do use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function. I reproduced only the first 3 rows:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'AL|ATFC|Year' : ['AL011851', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
        'Latitude': ['NaN', '28.0N', '28.0N'],
        'Longitude': ['NaN', '94.8W', '95.4W']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['AL|ATFC|Year'].replace('NaN', np.nan, inplace=True)
df['AL|ATFC|Year'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

outputs:

```py
  AL|ATFC|Year Latitude Longitude
0     AL011851      NaN       NaN
1     AL011851    28.0N     94.8W
2     AL011851    28.0N     95.4W
```

Answer (score 1):

`ffill` function is fill forward the value "where it is NA/NaN value", so you do not need NaN condition in `ffill`.

```py
df['AL|ATFC|Year'].ffill(inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks it worked for my case as follows:
`result.ffill(inplace=True)`
Strange enough the only other working way was:
`result = (
    df["Col3"]
    .str.extract(pat=f"^({'{0}|'.join(list_of_strings_elements)})".format("\."))
    .fillna(method="ffill")
)`

Comment: All those did not work:
`result.ffill(axis=0)`
`result.mask(result == "nan", None).fillna(method="ffill")`
`result.mask(result == "nan", None).ffill()`
`result.mask(result =='nan', None).fillna(method="ffill")`
`result.mask(result=='nan', None).ffill()`
`result.fillna(method="ffill").mask(result=='nan', None).ffill(inplace=True)`
`result.fillna(method="ffill")`
`result.fillna(method="ffill", axis=0)`